# Update a tree based on index Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tree

I have trees of the form:

```
data Tree a = Leaf | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

I created a function to look up the value of a node in a tree based on an in-order, left-to-right traversal.

```
getElem :: Tree a -> Int -> Maybe a
getElem Leaf _ = Nothing
getElem (Node l x r) n
    | s == n     = Just x
    | n < s      = getElem l n 
    | otherwise  = getElem r (n - s - 1)
  where
    s = size l
```

I now want to write a method to be able to update a tree. It should be able to take in a tree, an index and a value and update the node at that index with the value. So far I have:

```
update :: Tree a -> Int -> a -> Tree a
update Leaf _ _ = Leaf
update (Node l x r) index c
    | s == index      = (Node l c r)
    | index < s       = update l index c
    | otherwise       = update r (index - s - 1) c
  where
    s = size l
```

This function is able to add but it obviously returns just the added node itself. I want to be able to return the entire tree post the 'update' with the new node or return the tree as is if the index is out of bounds.

Could anybody give me some idea how to proceed with this?

Edit 1:

Okay, I understand that I am basically discarding the remainder of my tree when recursing here. So:

```
update :: Tree a -> Int -> a -> Tree a
update Leaf _ _ = Leaf
update (Node l x r) index c
    | s == index      = (Node l c r)
    | index < s       = update (Node l2 x r) index c
    | otherwise       = update (Node l x r2) (index - s - 1) c
  where
    s = size l
    l2 = l
    r2 = r
```

Edit 2(Silly me!):

```
update :: Tree a -> Int -> a -> Tree a
update Leaf _ _ = Leaf
update (Node l x r) index c
    | s == index      = (Node l c r)
    | index < s       = (Node (upd l index c) x r)
    | otherwise       = (Node l x (upd r (index - s - 1) c)) 
  where
    s = size l
```

It took me a bit to wrap my head around it. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: You `update` `l` (or `r`), and then *wrap* it in a new `Node` with the old `r` and `l` together, so you "reconstruct" a new tree.

Comment: Don't throw away `Node _ x r` when modifying `l` in the second case.  Don't throw away `Node l x _` when modifying `r` in the third case.

Comment: Regarding your edit: no, don't recursively call `update` on a new node that looks exactly the same as your input. Call `update` on the child node, and then *after* the call use the result to create the new tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since in Haskell all data is *immutable*, you can not "update" a tree, you construct a *new* tree. That tree might however have references to subtrees of the old tree. You thus do not per se construct a *completely* new tree.

You managed to create an "updated" node, so now the only thing that is missing, is to use the "updated" subtree in a *new* tree. In that tree, you can use the "old" value together with the *other* subtree to construct a new one, like:

```
update :: Tree a -> Int -> a -> Tree a
update Leaf _ _ = Leaf
update (Node l x r) index c
    | s == index      = Node l c r
    | index < s       = Node (update l index c) x r
    | otherwise       = Node l x (update r (index - s - 1) c)
  where s = size l
```

You might also need to change the `Leaf` case if you "count" a leaf as a node.

Trees with indices are not very common. It might also - in order to boost performance - be better to keep track of the number of items in the left subchild (or both), since then we can just pick the left or right subchild without counting the children. By keeping track of the number, for a *complete* tree, then updating the tree is an *O(log n)* operation, not an *O(n)* operation.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure it out based on the comments but it's nice to have a write up about it. And yes, the size optimization makes complete sense, might need to incorporate that separately